# In Go language, why the "<<0" operation will get 1?

Tags: go, bit-shift

I am quite confused about the go left shift operator. I run the following code:

```
package main

func main(){
    var x = 1 << 0
    println(x)
}
```

And I get 1. But I think the result should be zero.

Comment: Why should it be zero? Any number shifted by zero bits equals to itself.

Comment: You are shifting it with 0: meaning no shift at all.

Comment: Well, in any languange you'll get the same.!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, if it helped resolve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 << 0 means:

Take 1 and don't shift it. The result should be the original number: 1

Comment: I just think it means taking 0 and left shifting 1 bit, my mistake!